# Postman - Como eu envio o environment junto com minha collection?

Tags: postman

Tenho um Team Workplace, e nela uma collection, isso na web. No meu aplicativo do postman no pc eu criei um environment para passar algumas variáveis, como por exemplo, a url que é acessada (para podermos trocar se é o servidor de homolog ou o de produção).

Infelizmente toda alteração que eu faço só envia a collection, o environmentinfelizmente não sobe, e no postman console fica :

[image: Postman console informando que não tem environment]

No postman aplicativo, estou usando o environment para trabalhar, como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: Imagem aplicativo postman mostrando que existe um environment]

Acredito que quem utiliza postman já conhece esse problema, e espero que possam me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quem estiver com o mesmo problema, o Postman demora um bom tempo para subir o environment, cerca de 20 a 40 minutos.

Infelizmente o jeito é aguardar.